# UIAlertController not working in startup view in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I cannot seem to get the alert view to popup at startup of my view. Code is below.

```
import UIKit

class StartController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;

        startTest();
    }

    func startTest()
    {
        let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Test", message: "Testing alert controller", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

        alerta.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil));

        self.present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use UIAlertController in viewDidLoad unless you want to crash the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the issue is that in viewDidLoad the view hierarchy is not fully set. If you use viewDidAppear, then the hierarchy is set.

If you really want to call this alert in viewDidLoad you can do so by wrapping your presentation call in this GCD block to cause a slight delay

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Run UI Updates or call completion block
      startTest()
 }
```

or use in

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    startTest()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the `startTest()` in `viewDidAppear` method. It works for me.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    startTest()
}


func startTest()
{
    let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Test", message: "Testing alert controller", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

    alerta.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil));

    self.present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put it on `viewDidAppear:` method

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)  {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       startTest()
}
```